# SQL query combining 6 tables (with the same fields)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mariadb

Well I'm having a hard time finding a solution to what I need, I hope someone can help me.
There are 6 different stores with different products, some coincide in some stores and others not.

I have 6 tables with the same fields: Acronym, Name, Category, Quantity and Value.
I need to merge all the products in a same table with the reference of the "Acronym" between them.

My database does not support the FULL OUTER JOIN function.

I would need a return like that:

(* Qtt = Quantity)

[SQL RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZbQv.png)

Comment: Have you tried `UNION ALL`?

Comment: How can you be using sql server and state that your database doesn't support full outer join? That makes no sense.

Comment: I think you need to provide some details about your system. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I’m using mysql not sql server.
My system is:  
- Server version: 10.0.22-MariaDB-1
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503

I'm not a advanced user in sql, so I don't know exactly how to try this with UNION AL

Comment: Union is relatively simple...if the table schemas are identical this works. 
 select * from t1 union all select * from t2.    Please note that you tagged your question with SQL-Server (which references MSSQL).  Please edit your question and tag as MySQL instead.  Honestly it looks like you are trying to ask a pivot question and not a union question by your example data.  Er...or this is 6 left joins?

Comment: Is this for MariaDB or MySQL? (it does make a difference!) Please, only include tags that are actually relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Say t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6 are your tables. This should get you started:

```
select
     acro.acronym,t1.name t1name, t2.name t2name .....
from (
      select acronym from t1 union
      select acronym from t2 union
      select acronym from t3 union
      select acronym from t4 union
      select acronym from t5 union
      select acronym from t6
     ) acro
left join t1 on acro.acronym = t1.acronym 
left join t2 on acro.acronym = t2.acronym 
left join t3 on acro.acronym = t3.acronym 
left join t4 on acro.acronym = t4.acronym 
left join t5 on acro.acronym = t5.acronym 
left join t6 on acro.acronym = t6.acronym
```

The subquery `acro` simply builds a unique list of all acronyms from the 6 tables, then left joining the source tables will align the data to each (and all) acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes they don't have identical columns:

```
CREATE TABLE AllData
( SELECT acronym, this, that, ... FROM t1 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT acronym, this, NULL as that, ... FROM t2 ) -- no "that" in t2
UNION ALL
( SELECT acronym, NULL as this, that, ... FROM t3 ) -- no "this" in t3
...
```

If `acronym` is to be the `PRIMARY KEY`, then start this way:

```
CREATE TABLE AllData ( PRIMARY KEY(acronym) )
( SELECT ...
```

If you need a new `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then do this:

```
CREATE TABLE AllData ( id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id) )
( SELECT ...
```

If they do have identical columns, then ignore my notes about `NULL as ...`.